# How to read corrupted serialize object in java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have class a Person which has a list of Address classes.
I have able to save about 50 instance of a Person into a file via serialization.
I am expecting hundred. The other half was corrupted due to system crash.
Now when I read the files. I can deserialize about 50 files into an instance of Person. The other 50 display [B cannot be cast into Person....

My problem is how can I read back the information for this corrupted files specially the Address data for each Person.

Could you please suggest any methods to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: You can't. The data is corrupt. Bad luck.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good solution to this.

This kind of thing is why it is *inadvisable* to use Java object serialization as a substitute for a database.  And you possibly got into this situation through not testing your application adequately, not taking regular backups, etc.

However:

> Now when I read the files. I can deserialize about 50 files into an instance of Person. The other 50 display [B cannot be cast into Person....

This doesn't sound like the result of a crash.  Rather it sounds like you have incorrectly serialized `byte[]` objects instead of `Person` objects.  ("[B" is the internal type name for a `byte[]`.)  Unless those `byte[]` objects somehow contain serialized `Person` objects ... you are screwed.

(You cannot recover information from a file if the information isn't actually there.)